# alternative for digest -a sha256 command from solaris in linux

Tags: linux, utilities, checksum

I have file from solaris which have digest -a sha256. But this command is not working in linux. I want the alternative for this command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`digest` calculates a message digest, in your case SHA256. On linux you can get this by using the command:

```
sha256sum
```

You can either give it a filename as argument, or pipe information into it (which means if you just give the command, it will read what you type until you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)

On Ubuntu this command is available from the `coreutils` package.